# How to set the background image for a SKScene?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, sprite, sprite-kit

Since currently it is not possible to set the color to of a `SKScene` to `clearColor`, by doing

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {


        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor clearColor];

    }
    return self;
}
```

As seen here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780215/skcolor-clearcolor-returning-a-black-color-instead)

Then ***how can one set the background image for a `SKScene`? Please be as specific as possible, sample code would be great!***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `SKSpriteNode` centered in the scene:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        // Replace @"Spaceship" with your background image:
        SKSpriteNode *sn = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

        sn.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        sn.name = @"BACKGROUND";

        [self addChild:sn];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: this is working partially, as its actually stretching my image, not sure why it would be doing this...

Comment: If your image is called Spaceship.png, it'll stretch the image by a factor of two for retina displays. You'll need a file called Spaceship@2x.png for retina displays. This file shouldn't be stretched.

Comment: Also scene has a scaleMode property that defines how content of the scene gets scaled.

Comment: Is there not a more handsome way of doing this?

Answer (score 7):

swift 4 version:

```
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CheckIcon")
    background.size = frame.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    addChild(background)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me :

Put your code which calls/adds the scene from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
    {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width*2,skView.bounds.size.height*2)];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

As far as I know the reason for this is that the `skView.bounds`are different when the view is about to be layed out and when the view is shown. In general I found that the `height` and `width` are switched.

I found this solution from here:
[Background image size Sprite Kit Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471761/background-image-size-sprite-kit-game)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more elegant way, to ensure no matter what resolution you have now or in future, that your image will be the size of your background.

If you want to support banner ads, you'll have to reduce the height by 50 or 32 device units, and move the position up/down 25 or 16 pixels (portrait or landscape).
I also recommend having a different image for landscape vs portrait if you want to support both, or you'll have to start letter-boxing.

In the scene...

```
SKSpriteNode* background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"myBackground"];
background.size = self.frame.size;
background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:background];
```