# SpriteKit iPhone 6 simulator showing padding for background image

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit

Hello everybody I am learning SpriteKit iOS Xcode 6 and trying to add an image(640 X 1136) as a background from the sprite.atlas using the following code

```
    self.atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"sprite"];

    // set background
    SKSpriteNode * background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.atlas textureNamed:@"background"]];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild: background];
```

but the problem is in iPhone 6 simulator there is white border padding all across the image but it looks fine in iPhone 4s simulator.

[image: image with padded border]

Could you please advise me how to expand the image to full screen. Is there any setting that I need to add?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471761/background-image-size-sprite-kit-game

You can modify the layout by changing the aspect fill / fit / etc mode in ViewController.m's viewDidLoad function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone 6 screen size is 750 × 1334 in pixels so that should be the size of the background if you want it to fill the whole screen. You should add a bigger version for iPhone 6+.

Take a look at: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified